# Condicional if mais cleancode

Tags: php, revisão-de-código

A minha intenção é diminuir o tamanho da condição, pois achei que ela ficou extensa dificultando um pouco a legibilidade, e que talvez possa haver um jeito melhor de fazer isso:

- verificando as variáveis `$l1` e `$l2`, `$c1` e `$c2` juntas em vez de separadas.
- as 4 variáveis `$l1` e `$l2`, `$c1` e `$c2` podem ter qualquer valor numérico.
- quero que passe na condição somente se:

  - $l1 e $l2 forem maior ou igual a 1 e menor ou igual a 8
  - e $c1 e $c2 maior ou igual a 97 e menor ou igual a 104.

**A condição é sempre a mesma em todas as situações**:

- $l1 e $l2 entre 1 e 8 (inclusive)
- e $c1 e $c2 entre 97 e 104 (inclusive)

Tenho a seguinte condição

```
<?php

$l1 = 1;
$l2 = 7;
$c1 = 97;
$c2 = 104;

if(
    $l1 >= 1 && $l1 <= 8 
    && $l2 >= 1 && $l2 <= 8 
    && $c1 >= 97 && $c1 <= 104 
    && $c2 >= 97 && $c2 <= 104
)
{
  // ok
}
```

Comment: Como o autor esclareceu as regras do código, a postagem foi reaberta e a conversa ficou extensa, os comentários foram [movidos para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128606/) - Quem quiser participar, ler, adicionar ou esclarecer algo basta usar o link fornecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre acho uma boa extrair para funções. Isso ajuda e muito na legibilidade:

```php
<?php

$l1 = 1;
$l2 = 7;
$c1 = 97;
$c2 = 104;

if (
    entre1E8($l1)
    && entre1E8($l2)
    && entre97e104($c1)
    && entre97e104($c2)
) {
    // ok
}

function entre1E8($a) {
    return $a >= 1 & $a <= 8;
}

function entre97e104($a) {
    return $a >= 97 && $a <= 104;
}
```

Os nomes das funções são meramente ilustrativos, mas a ideia seria mais ou menos essa. Fica bem no sentido de escrita mesmo.

Se quiser "simplificar" mais...

```php
<?php

$l1 = 1;
$l2 = 7;
$c1 = 97;
$c2 = 104;

if (
    intervaloValidoL($l1, $l2)
    && intervaloValidoC($c1, $c2)
) {
    // ok
}

function intervaloValidoL($l1, $l2) {
    return entre1E8($l1) && entre1E8($l2);
}

function intervaloValidoC($c1, $c2) {
    return entre97e104($c1) && entre97e104($c2);
}

function entre1E8($a) {
    return $a >= 1 & $a <= 8;
}

function entre97e104($a) {
    return $a >= 97 && $a <= 104;
}
```

Aqui temos uma boa separação de responsabilidades, mas o preço é um aumento significativo no número de funções.

Comment: Uma dica, troque o nome *meramente ilustrativo* por `function between( $int , $val )`, assim pode-se aproveitar a função para outros tipos de validações. Basta passar o valor que será verificado e os parâmetros.